# Ajax delete function not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to use the jQuery Ajax function to delete a row in a MySQL database.
When I click on the posts "delete post" link I want it to trigger an `onClick` event which will run the delete row function.

This is my code so far:

Firstly display the posts with link to delete each one.

```
foreach($postarray AS $value){
echo '<div class="item">'.$value['post_title'].'  , <a href="#" class="delete_link" value="'. $value['post_id'] .'">Delete Post</a></div>';

}
```

Then the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".delete_post").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("value");

        function deletePost(id){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete_post.php",
                data: {id: id},
                success: function(data){
                    alert("Post deleted");
                }
            })
        }
    });

});
```

and the `delete.php` code:

```
//Start the session
session_start();
require_once('func/auth.class.php');
require_once('func/functions.php');
require_once('func/db.class.php');

// Check if user is logged in
if(!$_SESSION['is_admin'] || empty($_POST['id'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$post_id = $_POST['id'];
delete_post($post_id);
```

and the `delete_post()` function:

```
function delete_post($post_id){
        global $dbh;

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM mjbox_posts WHERE post_id = ?");
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() != 0){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Currently this method isn't deleting the posts from the database and I can't work out why.

Comment: I don't see the class `"delete_post"`

Comment: @jcho360 ya, i only see "delete_link" class

Comment: My bad, forgot to change that over when simplifying for stack

Comment: What is the ajax response that you can see from your browser debug tool (Firebug) ?

Comment: After you click the delete button, does anything happen? You might try echoing some code from the PHP page, and alerting it through your javascript to see if your ajax code is even accessing it correctly.

Comment: Your JavaScript doesn't seem to be have a call for `deletePost()`.

Comment: your ajax is calling "delete_post.php", but you say the file is "delete.php"?

Comment: I also recommend you to use some kind of debugger, like Firebug you can track the data sent and received and where is the error

Answer (score 1):

As jcho360 mentioned in a comment you have a mistake in the css class when binding to the click event.

Once you fix that it will still not work. When the click event is fired you are declaring a function that deletes posts, but you are not calling it. One fix could be to change it to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete_link").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("value");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete_post.php",
            data: {id: id},
            success: function(data){
                alert("Post deleted");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This way you are actually making the request when the click event is fired.

Further more I just noticed that in the ajax call you are requesting "delete_post.php", but you mention that your php file is called delete.php. That needs to be fixed as well.

You can use the inspector in your browser to see what happens when you click the link. Does it make the request at all? Is the id parameter set correctly? And so forth.